# How to offload browser audio links to background player for continued listening. 

Tags: audio

Is there an Android audio app that runs in the background and can have audio links offloaded to it (i.e. be the target of the intent) so the user can continue listening when the browser or foreground app that launched the audio link is closed? Or another way to configure this?

I'm on Jelly Bean and the built-in audio player sits in the foreground stopping the sound when I transition away from the foreground app.  For example, an MP3 podcast link.  The  issue occurs in Google Reader app too.

Comment: Is this a browse 'feature'?  Or, part of the 'design document' for Android app. design?  *It seems odd that both browser and reader app. have the same issue.*

Comment: The browser plays MP3s using one player and Google reader another but they both suffer me the same issue by not allowing me to leave the app without breaking the audio stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [BSPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsplayer.bspandroid.free) to be able to play some internet audio streams in the background.

One unique (?) feature which also I liked is that it has an intent filter for youtube links, i.e. clicking a Youtube link will offer BSPlayer as a choice - unlike the Google's Youtube app, with BSPlayer you can adjust the playback speed - I found it useful for listening to lengthy talk-only videos and presentations where you need to quickly get the gist without wasting too much time.

ps. I'm not affiliated in any way is the app developers.

Comment: I've switch to using BSPlayer too - it's advanced, suffices all my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came across [ServeStream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.servestream&hl=en), a free app in the Google Play store. It offloads podcasts and the like nicely into the background while you continue to use other apps on the device.

One great thing about ServeStream is it's open source, so you can [play with the code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/servestream/) if you wish.